# how do i enable my smooth scrolling to bring content to the middle of the viewport rather than to the top?

Tags: jquery, css

i'm working on a single page website ([trabo.in/raccoon/](http://trabo.in/raccoon/)) where the different sections of the site scroll into the viewport once selected in the nav. currently, when a link in the nav is selected the corresponding section smooth scrolls to the top of the viewport, rubbing with the top of the browser. i am trying to get it to scroll to the middle of the viewport, however, so that it is vertically centered as the nav bar is. is there any way to enable this in jquery? feel free to poke around in the js on that site, i for one have no idea what is going on...

many thanks and best wishes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick, low tech solution would be to give each section DIV a top margin in CSS. This won't center it completely, but it will at least stop it from touching the top of the screen.

EDIT: 
I believe this plugin has an option where it will notice the margins:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: i'm always a fan of the low tech route. i had tried this earlier, but it still (strangely) scrolled over the top margin and right to where the content starts (leaving the margin i added just above the viewport). :/

Comment: Just linked to a plugin that might help. :)

Comment: just peeked at it, looks promising. i'll read through it now :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with precise code on this since I would have to search for it myself, but what you need is ANCHORS (they should be the simplest thing there is).

You basically make an anchor in the middle of the page where you want it, and then edit the link URL to include the anchor.

As for smooth scrolling, you'd have to use javascript or jquery. There are a ton of scripts out there I am sure you can find one easily.

Comment: actually, i've already figured out how to do the smooth scrolling and how to go to 'anchors' (i've got a piece of code that recognizes the different sections and headers). my problem is that, when selected, a section scrolls to the top of your view rather than to be vertically centered (which i would prefer). thank you for your help, though. i'll try reposting.

Comment: if your section is a different page, then it might have to do with the jquery function (on page load) or something. you just need to forward the reference somehow (with a query url string maybe?) to the different page or section. track the values you forward to the function, check where you call the function and it has to be something with that that has a problem if it works otherwise.